# javascript How to go to home page, both Online and Offline (local hard disk)

Tags: javascript, url, location

location.href = '/';

works fine for online websites, but fails when you test the source on local hard drives (the root is C:// or file:// or some such)

How do you go to your website root index page BOTH online and on local disk?

Comment: When it is local, you generally would still have a normal website (one with a web server), on localhost, so then `'/';` would still point to the root of the site.

Comment: @Gray: I think he's talking about running the site from his local filesystem instead of a webserver.

Comment: @ThiefMaster That's what I thought as well, but I don't think that really makes sense to do. I think they should still have a webserver.

Answer (score 1):

You don't because there is no single "base" for file urls so what you are trying makes no sense in the first place.

If you want to test your code properly, you should install a webserver - otherwise the environment is very different and thus not really suitable for testing anyway.